# CI/CD pipelines Azure devops automatic merge after deploy release

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have a classic env. setup like following:

I have 2 branches: `Develop` and `Master`.

Is there any way in Azure DevOps to setup the following **rule:**

1. When a deploy is succeeded on dev environment (defined in the
   release pipeline of azure devops) **------>** create automatically a `pull request` to merge **develop** into **Master**.
2. or the other one: if a `Build` of **develop branch** is succeded **------->**
       create **automatically** a `pull request` to merge **develop into Master**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Edit:

**I just uploaded an extension that does it:**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest

---

You can use [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to create a Pull Request, so in the end of the Build / Release add a PowerShell task that do it, for example:

```
$body =  @{
             sourceRefName= "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
             targetRefName = "refs/heads/master"
             title = "PR from Pipeline"
     }

$head = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }
$json = ConvertTo-Json $body
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests?api-version=5.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $json -ContentType application/json
```

[image: Photo3]

You need to Allow scripts to access the OAuth token (check the checbox in the Agent Job options):

[image: Photo1]

Results:

[image]

I put the basic parameters in the body (from branch, to branch, title) but you can add more parameters like reviewers, check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Comment: If you receive the "You need the Git 'PullRequestContribute' permission to perform this action" error upon running the script in a release pipeline, who do you grant these permissions to?

Comment: @DickyMoore To the build service account, did you get the error even you enable the "Allow scripts to access....."?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, you can add a reviewer with the following: `"reviewers": [{"id": "d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db"}` How can I get the Id of the user I want to add as reviewer??

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish you can check the code of my extension that mentions above, there are different ways, check there.

Comment: Receiving this error with @ShaykiAbramczyk extension > "message":"TF401179: An active pull request for the source and target branch already exists."

Comment: @MANZARBEITIA it means that there is already PR open...

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk this issue only happened using YAML, when I used the classic editor it worked as expected.

Comment: @MANZARBEITIA and the settings are the same? please open an issue in my GitHub https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task/issues

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no build-in tasks for that, but you can script this yourself using the oauth token, or using your own auth to issue a request against the api.
2. pretty much the same approach can be used here, or you can use Branch policies to force pull requests to be validated before merging them to master (which in my mind is better, because merging from develop to master on every commit is pretty pointless).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can please provide more details about this : "you can script this yourself using the oauth token, or using your own auth to issue a request against the api." thanks

Comment: I've been doing this with github, you just need to call the api for merge: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/

Answer (score 0):

Using python and the [devops rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.0) people already mentioned you could do something like this.

```
# Tested in python 3.10
# pip install requests
import base64
import requests

# Fill the following variables with real values
personal_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=Windows
organization = "myorganization"
project_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
repository_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(f":{personal_access_token}", "ascii")), "ascii")
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Basic {authorization}"}

prs_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project_id}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_id}/pullrequests?api-version=5.1"

# create PR
response = requests.post(
    f"{prs_url}",
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps({
        "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/release",
        "targetRefName": "refs/heads/master",
        "title": "release to master",
    }),
)
```