# Create an automatic PR and complete it Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to create a flow where when a PR from branch a -> b is completed, an automatic PR from branch c -> d is created and completed.

I looked in this question but it doesn't mention auto complete

[CI/CD pipelines Azure devops automatic merge after deploy release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184170/ci-cd-pipelines-azure-devops-automatic-merge-after-deploy-release)

Also, can I set a specific policy to the automated PR so it would be auto complete?

**Update**

I tried using the following call:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
```

But I got the error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: Invalid 
pull request auto complete set by id. Valid values are either the current user identity id, or an empty guid (to unset 
auto complete)."
```

I tried to get the creator ID from the response but it's empty.

I tried to assign **Project Collection Build Service (msazure)** like I saw here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/298596/autocompletesetby-ignored-in-pull-request-rest-api.html

But I'm getting the error.

Comment: In the extension that mentioned in the link you provided there is an option to set "Auto complete" to the PR you create. (disclaimer: I'm the extension author)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, Thanks for responding back.
I can't use a 3rd party extension because of security issues so I'm trying to do it myself in the script.
What exactly do I need to pass as the Id in order to complete the PR

Comment: Is "Project Collection Build Service (msazure)" the right service to use?

Comment: do you try to update with PowerShell? Does it's during a build?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update via Powershell.
It happens when I try to run that specific step which contains the powershell script so I assume it's on runtime and not build (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Did you create the PR also in the script? I don't understand, is the script run in a build pipeline (you have task "PowerShell")?

Comment: Yes, it's a powershell script task that contains both the PR creation and after that the PR completion part. It's run in Release pipeline.

Comment: Ok, check the code of my extension: https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task/blob/10a0dcfc4b90c3459eab0709378d1953a2e62b82/task/createPullRequest.ps1#L584

Comment: I'm not sure what was the issue, but I have added $Response.createdBy.id and compilationOptions = "" and it works.
Thanks @ShaykiAbramczyk for your help! :)

Comment: Great! I added it also as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create the PR you can get the creator ID:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

$currentUserId = $response.createdBy.id
```

And send him in the update json body:

```
$body = @{
    autoCompleteSetBy = @{ id = "$buildUserId" }
    completionOptions = ""
}    

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Headers $head -Body $jsonBody -ContentType application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here after creation of PR, run the update operation to set Autocomplet. Check the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Updated the original post - I'm trying using this API but get an error (described above)